# WP gives 404 error for custom post type with GET variable

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, slug

I use the following method to add a $_GET Variable to my custom post type in wordpress.

```
 add_filter('query_vars', 'add_type2_var', 0, 1);

function add_type2_var($vars){ $vars[] = 'type2'; return $vars; }

add_rewrite_rule('/?c/(.[^/])/(.[^/])/(.*)$',"/c/$1/$2?type2=$3",'top');
```

My custom post type is non-hierarchical post. The links to the posts works without a problem but when I try to add something at the end after the slash the links stop working.

If I add `show` at the end of `http://127.0.0.1/wp/c/default/dd` `http://127.0.0.1/wp/c/default/dd/show` the link gives a 404 error. Though it works perfectly fine when I add numbers at the end like `http://127.0.0.1/wp/c/default/dd/123456` and I could also get the `123456` using `$_GET` in php.

I am not sure where the problem is but my guess is that wordpress gives an 404 error before my function. I have a function using `single_template` filter.

**UPDATE:**

I have added a function to `template_redirect.

```
function CPTTest() 
{
    if ( is_singular('cpt') ) 
    {
       echo 'cpt';
    }
    elseif ( is_singular() ) {
       echo 'post';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'none';
    }
    var_dump($_GET);
    die();
}
```

This works fine when I use the url `http://127.0.0.1/wp/c/default/dd/show`. Only problem is that it doesn't recognize it as a cpt post. But it does recognize `http://127.0.0.1/wp/c/default/dd/123456` as a cpt post. Same result when I used `wp` action instead of `template_redirect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers work because single posts can have pagination, and there is a rewrite rule to support that.

If you want to add an additional parameter after a permalink, add a [rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'show', EP_PERMALINK );
```

EDIT- Here's an internal rewrite example, assuming your custom post type slug is `type1`:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'c/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?type1=$matches[1]&type2=$matches[3]',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: My problem is that the endpoint text can change. `show` was just an example. But it could be different for each of the posts and also the post can have more than one endpoint. I can register the endpoints as I save the post but I dont think that would be good (unless there is a way to register an endpoint per post).

Comment: Can you explain your rewrite rule and the structure of your CPT? I think you would greatly simplify things if you make your rewrite rules internal.

Comment: Here is my previous question, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263988/get-slug-to-point-to-different-content-of-the-same-post/ . My custom post type is non-hierarchical and has a custom taxonomy in its slug ( `slug => 'c/%taxonomy%'`)

Comment: I would have solved that with an internal rewrite. See edit above.

Comment: Thanks :) I just came to that solution a while ago. Though in my case its `index.php?post_type=cpt&name=$matches[2]&type2=$matches[3]`. And I also added ` add_rewrite_tag('%type2%','([^&]+)');`.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you 404 by a fact that there is nothing found on your request. I guess it's because `type` is registered `query_var`. You can try to debug this situation with plugins: debug-bar (tab "Request") and debug-bar-rewrite-rules (Rewrite Rules).

Comment: but how does using numbers at the end work? I tried adding a function to die() at init echoing the `$_GET` variables and I see `show` or any other text I add in the url. So is there a way to have a function before wordpress gives 404 so I can check if it is a custom post type and make my own logic?

Comment: Slow down. Do you understand how Rewrite Rules work in Wordpres?  Yo create rule for your URL, whe your URL matchs your rule wp receive array of query vars ( ones received from url ), based on vars wp quering posts. Always. if posts not found youll get 404, if posts fond wp will search for a template and pass datat tp it ( using have_posts() etc... IMHO I already tald you whats wrong, you need to prove that using plugins i named.